# How do you mitigate the risk of stolen unencrypted data because you are using Cloud DNS to proxy the request that are sent to your server?

Tags: dns-spoofing, dnssec, waf, cloudflare

#### Goal

**My goal is to build a PWA**. I am new to programming and I believe it is better to start with NGINX.

I have not found a good article (explaining the security risk) about using the Cloud DNS (such as Alibaba Cloud DNS) to function as a WAF.

I am documenting it in a [README.md](https://github.com/jasononggo/docs)

#### My intention on why I ask this question

I am curious how we can use the Cloud DNS service safely. Note: I use Alibaba Cloud DNS.

> Cloudflare, as a proxy, decrypts your traffic internally to do what Cloudflare does, and then re-encrypts it for your visitors.

([source](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/does-cloudflare-proxy-servers-decrypt-my-data/145691))

#### Question

**How do you mitigate the risk of stolen unencrypted data because you are using Cloud DNS to proxy the request that are sent to your server?**

Reference: [Using Cloudflare's WAF = helps you mitigate direct attack (You block request except from the Cloudflare)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225428/does-cloudflare-masking-my-ip-make-my-server-more-secure)