# Reaching directly the origin server (through http) should be considered a vulnerability if the webapp use cloudfront?

Tags: web

**SCENARIO:**

webapp X use clodufront distributions to serve its content.
It's possible to contact directly the origin server and get the content with the following steps:

1. modify /etc/hosts to add <ORIGIN SERVER IP> <WEBAPP URL>
2. intercept the request to <ORIGIN SERVER IP>
3. change from https to http
4. modify Host substituting <ORIGIN SERVER IP> with <WEB APP URL>

If I reach the server in the described way the server response doesn't send the header `Via: cloudfront...` so I guess I'm talking directly to the origin server.

Is this behavior correct or should be addressed?

Comment: similar to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225428/does-cloudflare-masking-my-ip-make-my-server-more-secure

Comment: Is CloudFront meant to be a security control, or just a CDN? If the developer of the webapp meant to use it as a security control (for example integrating AWS Web Application Firewall), then such a misconfiguration can be considered a weakness, but not necessarily a vulnerability.